# GPO Rule Denied (Security) on a Computer

Tags: group-policy, wsus

I created a GPO that contains WSUS Group names, where the GPO Applied Computers should join to get their WSUS Updates.

In the Filtering I created an AD Group that contains the Computers of the domain, where I would like to use this GPO. I added myself and two other users. Its working for the two other users but not for me.

```
The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Client WSUS W10 Pilot
        Filtering:  Denied (Security)
```

I multiple checked I'm inside the group and also GPResult shows my computer is member of the group.
The group name is G-WSUS-Pilot

[Here you can see the settings of the GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0qX7.png)

[Here you can see the delegation tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae1gM.png)

[Here you can see im part of the group, and it totally looks like the same like others where worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGMPN.png)

Comment: Did you reboot your computer since adding it to the group? If not, you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Needed 3 weekday and my Computer was joined to the Group. I tried to restart the Computer 6 times but was not helpful, Time solved the problem.